# Linking Errors trying CS106B

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker-errors

I attempted to start a blank VS2008 project and follow along with the things being typed during the lectures, but I ran into a horrendous bunch of link errors. In the zip file for assignment 1 for the PC, there is a folder called CS106B.
First I told the compiler where the header files are (they're in the CS106B folder).

Next I had to tell the linker to use CS106CPPLib.lib. Ok, that's standard procedure...
But I can't make heads or tails of the errors that are coming out.

Here is the code from the session on class (lecture 4 iirc)

```
#include "genlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "simpio.h"

int main()
{
 ifstream in;
 cout << "Enter name: ";
 string s = GetLine();
 in.open(s.c_str());
  if(in.fail())
   Error("File didn't open");
 return 0;
}
```

Here are the resulting errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: inClassCoding, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::fail(void)const " (?fail@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char const * __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(int)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAEHH@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static bool __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eq_int_type(int const &,int const &)" (?eq_int_type@?$char_traits@D@std@@SA_NABH0@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eof(void)" (?eof@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAHXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::length(char const *)" (?length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAIPBD@Z) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(simpio.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _AtModuleExit(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?_AtModuleExit@@YAXP6AXXZ@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: __Fac_tidy already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(void)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __decode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(errmode.obj) : error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj) : error LNK2005: __strtoi64 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj) : error LNK2005: __strtoui64 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>J:\Projects\Coding\C++\CS106B\ProfessionalDevelopmentCS106B\test\inClassCoding\Debug\inClassCoding.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Build log was saved at "file://j:\Projects\Coding\C++\CS106B\ProfessionalDevelopmentCS106B\test\inClassCoding\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>inClassCoding - 60 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm completely new to Visual Studio, and help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Running OSX in a VirtualBox VM, I got this exact program to run in just a few minutes using XCode. The downside is that the VM cannot go full-screen and is relatively slow.

Comment: Worth trying the steps mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a incompatible library.

The library you added defines some symbols that is normally provided by the compiler libraries:

1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream > * __thiscall std::basic_ios >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) **already defined in CS106CPPLib.lib(genlib.obj)**

I would suspect that the CS106CPPLib.lib inhibits the linker to use other libraries that are provided by VS2008. You should consider that CS106CPPLib.lib is not compatible with VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `entire Project settings` it is difficult to answer exactly.

Probably [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f%28VS.80%29.aspx) might help you.

Also **double check the included libraries** to ensure that no libraries included more than once. It might be a cause. *I guess though.*

Answer (score 0):

Genlib defines functions that are being linked in with the MSVCPRTD library.

You could try to exclude the MSVCPRTD (in debug and MSVCPRT in release) from the solution by going to the project properties page, go to the linker section's input tab and enter the library name to the exclude field (or use the /NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCPRTD command line switch)

Another thing to check for is to make sure that the libraries are compiled in the same mode (/MT or /MD). I don't know what is defined in genlib (CS106CPPLib), so in your case, excluding the built-in library might not work, but it's worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test project 
`Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) or Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).`. is same as gtest project setting.